# Trying to use a list as a state with bloc library

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to use a List to store integers (just for experiments). I've made a Cubit and a State like so :

```
class NumberlistState {
List list = [];
NumberlistState({@required this.list});
}
```

then the Cubit :

```
class NumberlistCubit extends Cubit<NumberlistState> {
  NumberlistCubit() : super(NumberlistState(list: []));

  void adding(number) {
    var alist = state.list;
    alist.add(number);
    emit(NumberlistState(list: alist));
    print(state.list);
  }
}
```

in the main.dart I've got this Test class that renders buttons. These buttons are supposed to add their index number to the state :

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 50.0, 10.0, 0),
      child: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => NumberlistCubit(),
        child: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: 5,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 6, crossAxisSpacing: 8, mainAxisSpacing: 8),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Text(index.toString()),
                  onPressed: () {
                    BlocProvider.of<NumberlistCubit>(context).adding(index);
                  },
                )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The print(state.list) does shows the numbers after each click on the buttons in the console :

```
I/flutter (10293): [1, 2, 3, 0]
I/flutter (10293): [1, 2, 3, 0, 1]
I/flutter (10293): [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]
I/flutter (10293): [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
I/flutter (10293): [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

but the BlocBuilder fails to render the list with this code :

```
class TheContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TheContainerState createState() => _TheContainerState();
}

class _TheContainerState extends State<TheContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => NumberlistCubit(),
      child: Container(
        child: BlocBuilder<NumberlistCubit, NumberlistState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state.list.isEmpty) {
              return Text("Empty");
            }
            return Text(state.list.toString());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the list is always empty, even though it does print in the console. If I change the code to  `Text(state.list[0].toString());` the app crashes.

So the questions are :
Why the BlocBuilder doesn't work and how to render a container that displays the numbers clicked?

Why the state list seems to be empty for the BlocBuilder?

How to implement a state made of a List?

I always see this counterApp example and this project is based on it, but I cannot find a solution.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are violating one of BLoCs principles and mutating state. Instead of adding an item to an existing list in state, make a new copy with `List.of(state.list)..add(number)` (or, if you prefer the new syntax, `[...state.list, number]`) and emit it.

Comment: Awsome, thank you !